# Как распарсить ответ от сервиса

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Всем привет. Прошу не пинать в C# я новичОк :)

Подскажите пожалуйста, как распарсить ответ ?
Я делаю запрос на сторонний сервис , который возвращает мне ответ в JSON формате.
Тоесть строку.

Как и этой страке мне получить нужные значения ?

Вот пример кода :

```
 public GetFgoQueryHandler(IMapper mapper, DepartmentApiClient departmentApiClient, UserApiClient apiUserClient, FiasClient fiasApiClient)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _departmentApiClient = departmentApiClient;
        _apiUserClient = apiUserClient;
        _fiasApiClient = fiasApiClient;
    }

    public async Task<List<FgoResponse>> Handle(GetFgoRequest token, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var departments = await _departmentApiClient.GetReception(token.accessToken, OdpgDepartmentType.Fgo);
        var result = departments.ConvertAll(d => new FgoResponse
        {
            Name = "Федеральные государственные органы",
            Organ = d.Name,
            ContactsPhone = GetContacts(d.Users.Where(u => u.InOdpgRole(OdpgUserRole.Reception)).FirstOrDefault()),
            ReceptionContacts = GetAddressAsync(d.Addresses.FirstOrDefault(), token)

        });
        return result;
    }

    private async Task<string> GetAddressAsync(DepartmentAddressDto? address, GetFgoRequest token)
    {
        if (address != null)
        {
            var fullAddress = await _fiasApiClient.GetFullAddress(token.accessToken,
                new ESOG.Fias.Api.Model.GetFullAddressRequest
                { BaseAddressId = address.FiasId, Building = address.Building, Room = address.Room });
            var m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(fullAddress);
            var res = m.result;
            return fullAddress;
        }
        return "";
    }
    private List<string> GetContacts(UserDto? user)
    {
        var phones = new List<string>();
        //todo
        if (user != null)
        {
       
            foreach (var item in user.UserPhones)
            {
                phones.Add(item.FullNumber);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
        return phones;
    }
```

И адреса тоже в страшном виде, мне тут нужно поле result. В конеретном примере оно пустой, но в целом там будет нужная инфомрация потом (GetAddressAsync)  :

{
"result": "",
"id": 1382,
"exception": null,
"status": 5,
"isCanceled": false,
"isCompleted": true,
"isCompletedSuccessfully": true,
"creationOptions": 0,
"asyncState": null,
"isFaulted": false
}

Добавил такую модель :

```
    public class DepartmentAddress
{
    public string? Result { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? Exception { get; set; }
    public int? Status { get; set; }
    public bool? IsCanceled { get; set; }
    public bool? IsCompleted { get; set; }
    public bool? IsCompletedSuccessfully { get; set; }
    public int? CreationOptions { get; set; }
    public int? AsyncState { get; set; }
    public bool? IsFaulted { get; set; }
}
```

И такой код :

```
var res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DepartmentAddress>(fullAddress);
```

и теперь при запросе у меня постман возращает ошибку при десериализации.

Однако, когда я ставлю точку останвоа напротив адреса, и клацаю на лупу в свойстве - у меня там чистый адрес. Без все остальных свойств , описанных выше

Comment: Вы где-то await забыли, именуйте async методы как `ИмяМетодаAsync` и не будете забывать. Вы получаете сериализованный Task, а не нужный вам объект/ы класса. Судя по вашему коду вы не понимаете зачем нужны Task, async/await и как это использовать. Почитайте об этом вот [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)

Comment: @Aarnihauta да, не совсем понимаю. Но уже начал догазываться, что это мне приходит обертка от Task. Async\Awayt вроде не забыл нигде  в методе, который извлекает данные. За чтиво спасибо

Comment: @Aarnihauta Вроде внимательно перепроверил.
Везде есть Async\Await да и там только 1 метод имеет асинхроный запрос, он оозван по паттерну ИмяAsync . 
Только Handler не обозван по этому паттерну, но ен думаю что в этом проблема :) Обычно их не переименовываю, так как это метод дергает Mediatr без моего участия

Comment: Внутри `Handler` вызывается `department.ConvertAll`, этот метод точно НЕ асинхронный?

Comment: `GetAddressAsync` - авейта нет

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov попробовал поставить async перед d ? там где ConvertAll и await перед вызовом метода GetAddressAsync .
Но теперь ругается на преобразование Типа из Таск в обычный для переменной result

Comment: @Aarnihauta не уверен. Но как подказал Александр, внутри convertAll есть GetAddressAsync  который асинхронный. НО к чему привели поправки я написал выше. 
:(

Comment: после последних правки у result тип List<Task<DepartmentResponse>> значит где-то еще не хватает await, чтобы принять таску.  Но не понятно где. Перед deparement.ConvertAll хочется поставить, но не ставится
До меня уже дошло, что такска это аналог промиса.

Comment: Изучите асинхронную модель более подробнее, посмотрите гайды на ютубе и в msdn, *посмотрите как выглядит асинхронный код*, а затем уже приступите к рефакторингу уже существующего кода